# How to position text in HTML

Tags: html, css

Hi **HTML** and **CSS** gurus, I am trying to prepare a website for myself and got stuck in aligning texts. Need some help on it.

I have attached 2 screenshots

Desktop View:
[[image]]

Mobile View
[image]

**On Desktop View (Image 1)**

1. The blue colored background is a **png image** (made in photoshop) with a dimension of **400 x 603 px**. The black color background on the left or the red color background on the up are coded in HTML. I want the whole paragraph ("Many unit rent....gone by then") **to be aligned in the middle of the blue background** (from top where it is at present). How to code it dynamically so that whatever the screen size is the text remains in the middle?
2. I want the paragraph to have a **50 px gapping** from both sides of the blue background. How to achieve it?

**On Mobile View (Image 2)**

3. Whenever I try to resize my browser in **mobile view** and see the same paragraph it is shifting its base and going outside the blue box whereas it **should be in the middle**.

I have written the **HTML** and **CSS** code as:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="caption">
  <h3>Michael Corbett, who hosts NBC EXTRA&rsquo;s &lsquo;Mansions and Millionaires&rsquo; has observed:</h3>
</div>
<div class="img-cont fullh">
  <img src="img/background.png"/>
    <p id="text">Many units rent immediately, so it's kind of foolish to wait till the weekend just to get a peek; Chances are, it will be gone by then.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#text
{
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;    
    color:white;
    font-size:1.5em;
    font-weight:regular;
    left:50px;
    top:50px;
    width:80%;
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle of your code so we can see the entire thing? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c9tf26qm/

Comment: We need the entire page in fiddle. CSS and HTML are very sensitive to the layout of everything around them.

Comment: I am at a loss on how to add multiple js files in jsfiddle

Comment: If they are externally hosted use the external resources section on the left. If they are local copy all of the code into the javascript box.

Comment: Seems a use case for css media queries to me

Answer (score 2):

I think You should add Position relative to your upper div for solve this problem. you are not showing your full html or css thats why I am not sure this is right or wrong.

```
.img-cont.fullh {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```